# In Visual Studio 2022 on a C# Project, How Can _Usually_ but not always force namespaces to match file location?

Tags: c#

Usually I strongly prefer that namespaces should match the file location.

Every once in awhile, it is desirable to make an exception (for example, if I need classes to enable a newer language feature).

Is there a way I can surpress the error and stop my system from "fixing" this?

Comment: What error do you get from VS?

Comment: @stuartd, thanks for response, but Gilliduck already solved (below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This falls under warning [IDE 130](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0130)

```
#pragma warning disable IDE0130
// The code that's violating the rule is on this line.
#pragma warning restore IDE0130
```